# Language Support for Java server crashed 5 times in the last 3 minutes. The server will not be restarted

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

Suddenly I have this error in VSCode that I couldn't find any solution online for. There is one answer that said to install Lombbok Annotation extension and Java extension pack, but that still does not solve my problem.

Steps taken for troubleshooting:

- Opened each folder individually in the workspace and Java still works in those folders. No errors
- Copied all the files in the workspace to a different folder and open that folder in VSCode. Java still works there and there were no errors.

Strangely, I only get this error in the current workspace folder, so I don't really know what is happening there.

Comment: Open Command Palette and choose **Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace**, or even reinstall [java extension pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack). Does the question go away?

Comment: @MollyWang Cleaning the Java Language Server Workspace does work! Thanks a lot